# Sinch - iOS app crash when I hangup audio call

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, sinch, callkit

I am using Sinch service for audio/video calling along with CallKit.

When I hangup the call it get crash in iOS 13 devices, the error message it throwing is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'threading violation: expected the main thread'

When it happens, First I receive a video call then, I receive an audio call, now when I hangup the call it get crashed and giving me above error message and showing this thread cause issue. I searched on the internet and most of them are saying to put things on main thread, I did that still having the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code of yours? Its hard to know what you are talking about without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed on iOS SDK 4.2.5 released on 2020/05/15.

Comment: help me fix sinch backround

Answer (score 0):

We will look into, please share the SDK version you are using. 
Also, just to be clear, you get the second call (voice) after the first call is already over right? Otherwise the second call would never start (Phone is BUSY). Unless you are starting multiple Sinch clients, which is probably not the case.

Sinch Voice & Video Team

Comment: Thanks Jeorge for responding, I have already opened a ticket on 14th but still there is no response.

Yes, first call is ended for sure.
I have tested with these two versions 4.1.0 & 4.2.4.
I have used single global instance for all Sinch objects, there are no multiple copies of instance.